# Moving abroad: Can I use my computer overseas if I change the power supply unit (PSU) to one from that country?

Tags: power-supply, computer-building, hardware-rec

**Details**

I expect to move abroad soon. My current desktop computer was custom made in Japan.I was hoping to use it in Australia. I read somewhere that it is as simple as changing the power supply unit (PSU) over. Unfortunately I can't find any information to back that up.

In Japan the power supplied is 100V at 60Hz. In Australia the power supplied is 240V at 50Hz.

**QUESTION**

Can I use my computer overseas if I change the PSU to one from that country?

**EDIT**

I don't wish to use a power adapter. I want a more permanent solution. Thanks

Comment: Shameless product promotion! ;-) "Universal AC input from 90~264V — No more hassle of flipping that tiny red switch to select the voltage input!" (Corsair)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically many PSUs came with a switch in the back for switching between 110 and 220 volts. Today most are universal, adjusting to the input voltage. In either case you are covered.

So all you need is the cable, as most PSUs have a standard [C13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C13) mains input, finding the right mains plug for your destination should be easy.

Comment: Or check if the PSU is "universal", i.e. self adapting to the line voltage.  This might be rare for an ATX power supply.

Comment: @sawdust I didn't know those existed. +1 for mentioning it.

Comment: @sawdust I think these days most ATX PSUs are "universal", talking anything from ~90V to >250V at either 50 or 60Hz. But the specification needs to be checked (often written on the PSU).

Comment: @Richard - perhaps they are common!  Just looked at a 5-year old ATX PSU, and it has "universal" input for voltage & frequency.  Rats, could have written a more complete answer than Randolph.

Comment: Heh. It's not all about the rep. Feel free to modify my answer if you feel you have more to add.

Comment: @RandolphWest Done.